# How To: Create a JavaScript animation for random image displayer

Tags: javascript, animation

**I've created two functions to show random images with JavaScript. One for just random images and one for random images without duplicates. Now I'm trying to make kind of a Slotsgame spinner out of it, but only with one image at the time.**

*Below a example of a slotsgame:*

[image: Slotsgame Example]

So, now I'm trying to animate the Math.Random function, so that you see all the defined images spinning in the div where the image is called.

**HTML code:**

```
<form name="imageForm">
<table border=3>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input onclick="displayImage();" type="button" value="Display Random Image">
            <input onclick="displayImageND();" type="button" value="Display Random Image Without Duplicates">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img/image1.jpg" name="canvas" id="canvas" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The Images will be shown in the second `<td>`.

**JavaScript code:**

```
var imagesArray = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg", "image7.jpg", "image8.jpg"];
var gen_nums = [];

function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
        if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
}

function displayImage(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    document.canvas.src = 'img/'+ imagesArray[num];
}

function displayImageND(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, num)) {
        gen_nums.push(num);
        return document.canvas.src = 'img/'+ imagesArray[num];
    }
    return displayImageND();
}
```

I'm very new to JavaScript and this is my first "project" using it. So maybe you just laugh reading my question and that's okay ;). But I've googled a lot and can't seem to find the right solution for me. Please help me out.

**EDIT:**

What I wan't excactly is one image sliding down while the next one slides in for a random set amount of time. Each image is going to include a question or something like that. So when you click the button for a random image it has to spin like a spinning reel and randomly ends on a image with question. I've tried to include some examples I could find online in to my own code. 
Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDsMa/1/
But because of my lack of JavaScript knowledge I couldn't get it to work.

I hope this edit is more clarifying concerns my question.

Comment: A note on ease of reading and maintainability for anyone reading your code (including you in the future!), using the name "canvas" for your target could be confusing; there is a [`canvas` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Canvas). Seeing `document.canvas` could lead someone to think you are doing something with a `canvas` rather than a normal image tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "animate" and "spinning"? Do you just want to change the currently displayed image over time (relatively easy to do), or do you actually want one image sliding down while the next one slides in above it like a reel spinning (much more involved to do). Do you want it to "spin" for a set amount of time? Stop after a certain number of images? More detail on how exactly you want it to work would help anyone answering this. As is, it's a little vague to point you in the right direction. Have you already tried something to do it? If so what?

Comment: @UselessCode Thankyou for your answer. I've edited my question (see EDIT: at the bottom of my post), I hope this will help.